# React jsx version of html (using different tags, but same attribute and logic) isn't triggering jquery on('change') method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs, redux

I'm migrating jQuery/javascript code into React piecemeal and for some reason I can't activate the "change" event when a value is changed React/Redux as it it's down in html. Does anyone know why this might be the case that the "change" event isn't being fired?

The original html code:

```
<div class="form-group row" style="margin-top: 10px!important;" >
  <div class="col-md-2"><lang data-key="Resolution" /></div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
     <select class="form-control" id="screensize" style="width:100%;">
        <option value="1920x1080" >1920 x 1080</option>
        <option value="1680x1050">1680 x 1050</option>
        <option value="1440x900">1440 x 900</option>
        <option value="1280x800">1280 x 800</option>
        <option value="1024x768">1024 x 768</option>
        <option value="800x640" selected>800 x 640</option>
     </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

My react version of this.

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        ...
        settings: state.settings,
    };
};
class DomStateWrapper extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
   }
   render() {
      return (
          <div>
             ...
             <input
                id="screensize"
                value={this.props.settings.resolution}  //** I have confirmed that this attribute gets its value from the redux store successfully
             />
             ...                      
          </div>

      )
   }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(DomStateWrapper);
```

The jQuery code I'm using to consume the change

```
      $(document).on("change", "#screensize", function(e) {
        var sizes = $(this)
          .val()
          .split("x");
        if (showWin != null) showWin.resizeTo(sizes[0], sizes[1]); // resize the popup
      });
```

Overall, the original html version of this code which uses ,  and sets its value and triggers the change method in the jquery code, but when I do it in react/redux, using , that .on() method is never triggered. I also used this website as reference for the "change" event.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event

Comment: Why are you using jquery in your reactjs app?

Answer (score 1):

So getting a lot of flak for this question for having jQuery in React. I don't like it either, but it's not by choice when the task is to migrate from jQuery to React. Anyways, for anyone interested, the reason why this was happening is because it seems that the jQuery onChange event is being called either before or simultaneously with redux changing state. So to keep the jQuery change method while also updating state, the quick fix implemented was adding the action to the window:

```
window.reduxStore = store;
window.reduxActions = {resizeProjector}
```

So giving jQuery access to the redux action function `resizeProjector`, allowed us to update the jQuery code with:

```
$(document).on('change', '#screensize', function(e) {
   var sizes = $(this)
     .val()
     .split('x');
   reduxStore.dispatch(
     reduxActions.resizeProjector({
       width: sizes[0],
       height: sizes[1],
     }),
   );
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use jQuery in your ReactJS app.

Do this instead:

```
<input
  onChange={resizeWin}
  value={this.props.settings.resolution}  //** I have confirmed that this attribute gets its value from the redux store successfully
/>
```

```
const resizeWin = e => {
  var sizes = e.target.value.split("x");
  if (showWin != null) showWin.resizeTo(sizes[0], sizes[1]); // resize the popup
}
```

Comment: I know this, and this is not by choice. We are migrating jQuery to react but have to do so piecemeal. For now, we have to use the jQuery code as to not break the rest of the application.

Comment: @showduhtung in that case, tell me when are you registering that .on('change') event for screensize?

Comment: Well in the first implementation where the index.html uses <select id="screensize"> and <option>, if a new option is selected, it changes the value attribute of the <select> tag firing the .on('change') event.

In my implementation, I have a Menu/MenuItem (from mui) whose onClick event triggers a change in the redux store. The store change then updates the value in the <input id="screensize"/> which I had hoped would've triggered the jQuery's .on("change") event, but doesn't.

Comment: But when do you register that jQuery.on('change')

Comment: Oh it's part of a js file which lives in <body> of the index.html as ```<script src="js/dev/tjc_main.js"></script>```

Comment: Most likely the element #screensize doesn't exist when that change event is registered (that's why it's never called).

Comment: Can you check if that is the case? try and log $('#screensize') to the console to see if it exists

Comment: Yup I've confirmed it exists

https://imgur.com/a/RfOJ1Kd
https://imgur.com/a/vMINeq9